# How To Check if player Is Holding Tool in Hand

Tags: roblox

i want this roblox script to print key and do the other things when i hold the key in my hand and if it is in my backpack.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local lock = script.Parent

local function onTouched(hit)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if player then
        print(player)
        local backpack = player:FindFirstChild("Backpack")
        if backpack then
            print(backpack)
            local Key = backpack:FindFirstChild("SilverKey")
            if Key then
                print(Key)
                script.Parent.CanCollide = false
                script.Parent.Anchored = false 
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Assuming you have a part named "Lock" in the game
local lock = script.Parent -- Change this to the actual lock object

lock.Touched:Connect(onTouched)
```

i tried using chatgpt but it dident work i did not understand how other peaple haw done it before

Answer (score 0):

Check if the parent is the Character or the Player. If it's the character, it's being held, but if it's the player then it's in the inventory.

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it by finding the players player and checking if it has the tool as a Child.